# how to use multiple different a href link on each different images?

Tags: php, arrays, image, indexing, href

how to use multiple different `a href link` on each different images? and images are getting from the `folder or directory?

**Php Code**

```
<?php 

$directory = "data/uploads/bottomslider/";

if (glob($directory . "*") != false)
{

$filecount = count(glob($directory . "*"));

}
$files_index = glob("data/uploads/"."bottom"."slider/*.*");

for ($i=0; $i<$filecount; $i++)
{
$num2 = $files_index[$i];

?>  

<li class="jcarousel-item"><a href=""><img src="<?php echo $num2;?>" 
style="height: 119px!important; width:132px !important;"/></a></li>

<? }?>
```

**For Example**

```
i want like this?

<a href="google.com">Image1</a>
<a href="facebook.com">Image2</a>
<a href="yahoo.com">Image2</a>
```

Comment: <a href="<?php echo $num2;?"> if $num2 contains image path..

Comment: @Ashish yes `$num2`contains image path but i want to use `a href lin like this google.com,yahoo.com` on each different images

Comment: so better u make array of links, but remember ur link array must be same size of $filecount..u can use same loop and access links from array

Comment: @ashish but how could i call the link on different `$num2`

Answer (score 1):

I did not test the code. But this should work. Assuming that the folder "data" is in the root of your webpage.

```
$directory = "data/uploads/bottomslider/";
if(file_exists($directory)) {
    $files = scandir($directory);
    $output = "";
    foreach($files as $key => $value) {
        if($value != '.' && $value != '..' && $value != '.quarantine' && $value != '.tmb') {
            $output .= '<li class="jcarousel-item"><a href="/'.$directory.$value.'"><img src="/'.$directory.$value.'"
style="height: 119px!important; width:132px !important;"/></a></li>';
        }
    }
    //$output contains all the images.
    echo $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$directory = "data/uploads/bottomslider/";
$link = "";
if (glob($directory . "*") != false)
{
    $filecount = count(glob($directory . "*"));
}
$files_index = glob("data/uploads/"."bottom"."slider/*.*");
//this array must be same size like number of images 
$array1 = array('www.yahoo.com', 'www.google.com', 'www.facebook.com', 'www.stackovrflow.com', 'www.blahblah.com');
for ($i=0; $i<$filecount; $i++)
{
    $num2 = $files_index[$i];
    $link = $array1[$i];

?>  

<li class="jcarousel-item"><a href="<?php echo $link?>"><img src="<?php echo $num2;?>" 
style="height: 119px!important; width:132px !important;"/></a></li>

<?php
}
?>
```

Give full path of link like "https://www.facebook.com/"